# SQL Injection in SQL Server 2008 - is it possible to enable XP_CMDSHELL without stacked queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working on a pentest/bug bounty at this current moment in time. I found a POST MS SQL Injection in a POST parameter concerning authentication codes; I verified the vulnerability by pulling the version which was:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (Intel X86) Jul 9 2008 14:43:34
Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation 
Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 6.0 <X86> (Build 6003: Service Pack 2)
```

Then I wanted to see what user was executing the queries, so I switched my payload to give that information with suser_name() & I found out the queries were being executed by system administrator or sa. Most of us know this can end badly, but here's the problem I'm faced with:

Since 2005 xp_cmdshell has been disabled by default. That means by in order to abuse this particular issue, I would have to enable it through configuring it. I've been looking for documentation on how to do this but a few of the people I've been asking have told me it requires stacked queries to be allowed - which they are not.

Is there a way around this? What about in terms of local file access? I just want to prove the critical issue of this vulnerability outside of being able to pull system level information with the injection. Obviously, executing code or local file access would be ideal..

Any ideas or comments are welcome. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Isn't the fact that sa can actually drop all the databases on the server considered risky enough?

Comment: Yes, it is; But I am working with the concerned company & just want to ensure they understand the full risk factor of this vulnerability. I just want to check & see if there's a way to execute code without stacked queries so I can include that in my write up.

Comment: Try using `;` (semicolon) to separate multiple statements